# Why cannot delete image cache in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, html, image, magento, caching

When I upload a **new product image** using the admin panel, and **I delete the old image**
  the old image keeps coming in the frontend! **but it doesnt exist in backend**!

I have tried to disable **all cache settings**, **clear image cache**, **refresh settings**, **manually delete the cached images from the path**, but nothing seems to get rid of the cached images.  **What am I missing??**

The folder from which is getting the images is 
**\www[mymagento]\media\catalog\product\cache**

**Even If I delete the folder is re-created again!**

And It contains the already deleted images!

Its a permission issue? Somebody has faced this problem again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you use Flat product index and the index is not up to date. In the flat tables the old image is referred.
Rebuild your index (while you are at it, you can rebuild all the indexes) and clear the image cache after the indexes are rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you Marius!Solved!